# why is my console returning id is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

I am trying to make simple tabs program in js, i am new to js and dont have much knowlage about it,so be understandable. I set my code up using this tutorial https://wesbos.com/javascript/06-serious-practice-exercises/tabs. And this is my code
**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tabs">
      <div role="tablist" aria-label="Programming Languages">
        <button role="tab" aria-selected="false" id="js">
          JavaScript
        </button>
        <button role="tab" aria-selected="false" id="ruby">Ruby
        </button>
        <button role="tab" aria-selected="false" id="php">
          PHP
        </button>
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="js" hidden>
        <p>JavaScript is great!</p>
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ruby" hidden>
        <p>Ruby is great</p>
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="php" hidden>
        <p>PHP is great!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="./tabs.js"></script>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
button[aria-selected="true"] {
  background: orange;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
const tabs = document.querySelector('.tabs');
const tabButtons = tabs.querySelectorAll('[role="tab"]');
const tabPanels = tabs.querySelectorAll('[role="tabpanel"]');

function handleTabClick(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
tabButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', handleTabClick));

function handleTabClick(event) {
  // hide all tab panels
  tabPanels.forEach(panel => {
    panel.hidden = true;
  });
  // mark all tabs as unselected
  tabButtons.forEach(tab => {
    // tab.ariaSelected = false;
    tab.setAttribute('aria-selected', false);
  });
  // mark the clicked tab as selected
  event.currentTarget.setAttribute('aria-selected', true);
  // find the associated tabPanel and show it!
  const { id } = event.currentTarget;
}

const tabPanel = tabs.querySelector(`[aria-labelledby="${id}"]`);
console.log(tabPanel);
tabPanel.hidden = false;
```

Comment: what is the name of your js file and where its located?

Comment: all the code is writen in code playground in jsfiddle.net

Comment: You declared `id` with `const` which means that it scoped (only exists) within the block (the body of your `handleTabClick` function in this case). Your `tabs.querySelector(`[aria-labelledby="${id}"]`)` is outside of the function, so `id` doesn't exist there. Why are the last 3 lines outside of this function?

Comment: That is the solution, the problem was that the id scope didnt see const tabPanel, I had put  it outside the function because i didnt know that it mattered and the code now works, thanks for your commitment